# Serving a static file Gulp generated Aurelia SPA with IIS and a Asp.Net web API

Tags: asp.net, iis, aurelia

I've developed a web api in Asp.Net and a single-page application which is calling the restless api.

The SPA is a user interface created with Aurelia, and currently I'm using Gulp in my development environment, which gives me a dist folder with all my static .js/.html files.

Now that i need to deploy my SPA in production/staging (the api is already set up and running), given the limitations at work my only option is serve my SPA consisting of static html/js/css/img files using IIS.

How would I go from gulp watch in development mode, to actually integrating it with my existing currently live Asp.Net web api?

I guess I have to copy over my dist folder to my Asp.Net project where my web api application resides (either copy it to the existing web api project, or create another project for the SPA static files, under the same solution?) in visual studio, but what next?

As I mentioned I'm using Aurelia with gulp, which means the app.html/.js files inside are where the application starts.

**Edit**

I've accepted Jeremy's answer, however I decided to create a separate blank asp.net 5 project. As Jeremy correctly said, I had to add the following folders and files:

```
 - mySolution
     - api (exiting api project)
     - user-interface (my newly created Aurelia spa)
         - wwwroot
             - dist
             - images
             - jspm_packages
             - scripts
             - styles
             - config.js
             - index.html
```

I followed the tutorial here: http://shellmonger.com/2015/07/10/the-aurelia-tutorial-revisited/ however I had a few problems with Startup.cs and project.json due to some breaking changes in beta5 it'd seem.

The solution was here: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25#issuecomment-106141289

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
               .AddJsonFile("config.json", optional: true)
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        }
```

But in order to make it work I ended up changing the following lines in project.json

```
"Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta4",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4"
```

**to beta5 instead of beta4**

```
"Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5"
```

And to my great surprise after it compiled I had my Aurelia application up and running without any futher customizations needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy your `index.html`, `config.js`, `dist` folder, `jspm_packages` folder as well as any files/folders containing other image/css assets over to the folder (or subfolder) containing your API application hosted by IIS.

If you're doing any bundling you might not need to copy all of the `jspm_packages` folder, it depends on your bundle configuration.